# inconsistent TablixHeader.Size in Report Builder 2

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder

I get this nonsensical error seemingly randomly in Report Builder 2.0.  Does anyone know why it comes up or how I can get rid of it?

> The TablixRowHierarchy in tablix 'Tablix1' contains an inconsistent TablixHeader.Size in one or more of the TablixMembers that contain headers for TablixRow 2. TablixRow 2 has an expected total header size of 314.959993338585mm and an actual total header size of 314.960003936291mm. The total header size for each TablixRow created by the TablixRowHierarchy must be equal.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I got this error when merging cells in a row in the grouped rows section. If you do not merge all the cells up to the data columns, you get this error. If you unmerge the cells, or merge all cells up to the data columns, the error dissapears.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into this as well but I don't understand your solution. I know it's been a while but could you elaborate by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unmerge the cells in the top left of your tablix

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I don't know why, it just works. Is not necessary to unmerge the cells. The error happens when you add a column inside a group. What you have to do is to resize each column on tablix to the size you want, but you should resize all of them. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing columns work for me, I just resize few columns.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a cause of this, a way to replicate it and a solution after spending a while trying to fix my report which now would not upload/deploy due to the error.

It is caused by first merging cells in one column, then highlighting the newly merged cell and the adjacent cells to the right (which are still split) and then merging those with the left one.

The way to make it work without this bug is to merge the two cells in the left and right columns separately then merge them together.

Imagine you start with the following layout:

[image: Unmerged]

Then you merge the left cells:

[image: Left merged]

Then lastly you merge the lot in a single action:

[image: Right merged with left in single action]

This then triggers the bug and means the report will not upload to the report server.

The way to work around this is to again start with the unmerged version (you can undo the above steps if the report is still open or otherwise must unmerge these separately)

So starting with the unmerged version:

[image: unmerged again]

Now merge the left cells:

[image: Left merged again]

Now merge the right cells:

[image: Right merged]

Then merge the two sets of already merged columns:

[image]

This avoids the bug and you end up with exactly the same output.

Also the bug does not occur in Visual Studio and if you attempt to open a report in Visual Studio once the bug has occurred it can't handle it and shows the tablix twice and then stops responding and must be closed from Task Manager.